# Android Webview GIF growing heap dramatically over time

Tags: android, webview, memory-leaks, heap-memory, animated-gif

In a nutshell, I'm trying to display an animated GIF in a webview. This webview is in a list item. So, there is a listview of different gifs.

I'm setting the gifs on the listview like so:

```
View v = convertView;
if (v == null || position == 1) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.routine_exercise_item, parent, false);
}
TextView t = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.routine_exercise_num);
t.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.other_exercise) + " " + (position));

t = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.routine_exercise_description);
t.setText(mitems.get(position).description);



WebView anim = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.routine_exercise_gif);
anim.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + mitems.get(position).imagePath);
anim.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

I'm doing this inside getView of an ArrayAdapter<> subclass.

Everything loads just fine and the gif works... However, as soon as it's displayed, my heap grows like crazy. It only takes 30-45 seconds for the heap to hit 32MB on my EVO 3d and crash.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong for such a memory leak to happen.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oof. A `WebView` per `ListView` item? Yeah, they're heavy. I don't necessarily see anything that would cause the behavior you're seeing, but utilizing a `WebView` just to show a GIF is a bit overkill. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://androidosbeginning.blogspot.com/2010/09/gif-animation-in-android.html) on a `View` subclass that uses `android.graphics.movie` to display animated GIFs. Might be lighter than WebViews.

Comment: I followed the tutorial and it worked fantastically. I was hoping for something quick and easy. After looking past this solution I decided on something that's just drag and drop.

Turns out it's not worth it. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Brain, could you give me another advance? We used f*** Cordova and it is all webView. I should fixed memory leak from gifs in WebView. Do your have any ideas?